# parsing pandas data frame base on conditions and save it to a csv

Tags: python, csv, pandas

so i have a data frame from (csv very long) i would like to parse it based on a condition(every time column D come back to zero creat a new data frame name data#) on one of the column and save them to a new csv file as i go. i know that in python i can do mp.mlab.find(mp.logical_and(D== 0.0)) it will give me the indexes where D=0 but i don't know how to then identify the beginning of that sequence and its end and parse it to a new data frame keeping all of the columns.
`data
     A          B         C     D  E  F  H
0    0  12.000000 -8.000000   0.0  1  1  2
1    1  12.000000 -8.000000   0.0  1  1  1
2    2  12.100000 -8.100000   0.0  1  1  0
3    3  12.020000 -8.000000   0.0  1  1  1
4    4  12.010000 -8.000000   1.2  1  1  0
5    5  12.000000 -8.000000   1.3  1  1  2
6    6   1.500000 -8.200000   1.9  1  1  1
7    7  12.600000 -8.000100   2.0  1  1  1
8    8  12.400000 -8.000000   3.5  1  1  2
9    9  12.200000 -8.050036   6.0  1  1 -1
10  10  12.020000 -8.053374   7.8  1  1  2
11  11  12.000000 -8.056713   9.0  1  1  1
12  12  12.000000 -8.060051  12.5  1  1  1
13  13   1.500000 -8.063389  18.0  1  1  1
14  14  12.600000 -8.066728  19.0  1  1 -1
15  15  12.000000 -8.070066  15.0  1  1  2
16  16  12.400000 -8.073404  16.0  1  1  1
17  17  12.300000 -8.076743  10.0  1  1  0
18  18  12.000000 -8.080081   5.0  1  1  2
19  19  12.300000 -8.083419   4.5  1  1  0
20  20  12.600000 -8.086758   1.2  1  1  1
21  21  12.000000 -8.090096   0.0  1  1  1
22  22  12.000000 -8.093434   0.0  1  1  0
23  23  12.000000 -8.096773   0.0  1  1  1
24  24  12.200000 -8.100111   1.5  1  1  2
25  25  12.200000 -8.103449   3.0  1  1  2
26  26  12.300000 -8.106788   7.0  1  1  0
27  27  12.500000 -8.110126   5.0  1  1  2
28  28  12.000000 -8.113464   2.0  1  1 -1
29  29  12.300000 -8.116803   0.0  1  1  1
30  30  12.400000 -8.120141   0.0  1  1  1
31  31  12.600000 -8.123479   0.0  1  1 -1
32  32  12.500000 -8.126818   0.0  1  1 -1
33  33  12.000000 -8.130156   0.8  1  1  1
34  34  12.360000 -8.133494   1.6  1  1 -1
35  35  12.370909 -8.136833   2.0  1  1  2
36  36  12.381818 -8.140171   5.0  1  1  1
37  37  12.392727 -8.143509   4.0  1  1  0
38  38  12.403636 -8.146848   3.0  1  1  0
39  39  12.414545 -8.150186   2.6  1  1  1
40  40  12.425455 -8.153524   1.2  1  1  2
41  41  12.436364 -8.156863   0.0  1  1  1
42  42  12.447273 -8.160201   0.0  1  1  1
43  43  12.458182 -8.163539   0.0  1  1 -1
44  44  12.469091 -8.166878   0.0  1  1  0
45  45  12.480000 -8.170216   0.0  1  1  1
46  46  12.490909 -8.173554   2.5  1  1  2
47  47  12.501818 -8.176893   3.0  1  1 -1
48  48  12.512727 -8.180231   7.0  1  1 -1
49  49  12.523636 -8.183569   9.0  1  1 -1
50  50  12.534545 -8.186908  15.0  1  1  0
51  51  12.545455 -8.190246  26.0  1  1 -1
52  52  12.556364 -8.193584   9.0  1  1  0
53  53  12.567273 -8.196923   7.0  1  1 -1
54  54  12.578182 -8.200261   6.0  1  1  0
55  55  12.589091 -8.203599   4.3  1  1  1
56  56  12.600000 -8.206938   3.3  1  1  2
57  57  12.610909 -8.210276   2.3  1  1  0
58  58  12.621818 -8.213614   2.1  1  1 -1
59  59  12.632727 -8.216953   0.9  1  1 -1`

i would like to get some thing like

`data1
     A          B         C     D  E  F  H
0    0  12.000000 -8.000000   0.0  1  1  2
1    1  12.000000 -8.000000   0.0  1  1  1
2    2  12.100000 -8.100000   0.0  1  1  0
3    3  12.020000 -8.000000   0.0  1  1  1
4    4  12.010000 -8.000000   1.2  1  1  0
5    5  12.000000 -8.000000   1.3  1  1  2
6    6   1.500000 -8.200000   1.9  1  1  1
7    7  12.600000 -8.000100   2.0  1  1  1
8    8  12.400000 -8.000000   3.5  1  1  2
9    9  12.200000 -8.050036   6.0  1  1 -1
10  10  12.020000 -8.053374   7.8  1  1  2
11  11  12.000000 -8.056713   9.0  1  1  1
12  12  12.000000 -8.060051  12.5  1  1  1
13  13   1.500000 -8.063389  18.0  1  1  1
14  14  12.600000 -8.066728  19.0  1  1 -1
15  15  12.000000 -8.070066  15.0  1  1  2
16  16  12.400000 -8.073404  16.0  1  1  1
17  17  12.300000 -8.076743  10.0  1  1  0
18  18  12.000000 -8.080081   5.0  1  1  2
19  19  12.300000 -8.083419   4.5  1  1  0
20  20  12.600000 -8.086758   1.2  1  1  1
21  21  12.000000 -8.090096   0.0  1  1  1`

`data2
22  22  12.000000 -8.093434   0.0  1  1  0
23  23  12.000000 -8.096773   0.0  1  1  1
24  24  12.200000 -8.100111   1.5  1  1  2
25  25  12.200000 -8.103449   3.0  1  1  2
26  26  12.300000 -8.106788   7.0  1  1  0
27  27  12.500000 -8.110126   5.0  1  1  2
28  28  12.000000 -8.113464   2.0  1  1 -1
29  29  12.300000 -8.116803   0.0  1  1  1
30  30  12.400000 -8.120141   0.0  1  1  1
31  31  12.600000 -8.123479   0.0  1  1 -1
32  32  12.500000 -8.126818   0.0  1  1 -1
33  33  12.000000 -8.130156   0.8  1  1  1
34  34  12.360000 -8.133494   1.6  1  1 -1
35  35  12.370909 -8.136833   2.0  1  1  2
36  36  12.381818 -8.140171   5.0  1  1  1
37  37  12.392727 -8.143509   4.0  1  1  0
38  38  12.403636 -8.146848   3.0  1  1  0
39  39  12.414545 -8.150186   2.6  1  1  1
40  40  12.425455 -8.153524   1.2  1  1  2
41  41  12.436364 -8.156863   0.0  1  1  1`

`data3
...
...
...`

Any help will greatly be appreciated.
thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finding the rows where `D` has gone back to 0 can be done like this:

```
df['back_to_0'] = (df['D'] == 0) & (df['D'].diff() < 0)
```

i.e. the value is 0 and the value has gone down since the last row.

Then we create a grouping variable:

```
df['time_group'] = df['back_to_0'].cumsum() + 1
```

And we can split by `time_group` to get individual data frames:

```
grouped = df.groupby('time_group')

for group_number, group_data in grouped:
    print(group_data.head())
    # Could also do group_data.to_csv() here if you want
    # to save the individual pieces as separate files
```